# How can I split a string likes shells do to populate ARGV?

Tags: ruby, string, command-line

I want either a Ruby method or a regular expression that will let me split a string of command-line arguments into an ARGV-like array. What I am asking is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706551/parse-string-into-argv-argc), but in Ruby.

I'm writing unit tests for a Ruby program that processes command-line input using Trollop (though this question would be the same for any other option parser).

The method I want to test looks like this:

```
def parse_args(args)
  Trollop::options(args) do
    # ... parse options based on flags
  end
end
```

In my program, I call `parse_args(ARGV)`. In my test, I thought I could just pass in a string split on spaces, but this is not the behavior of ARGV. Compare the following:

```
./argv_example.rb -f -m "Hello world" --extra-args "-vvv extra verbose"
=> ["-f", "-m", "Hello world", "--extra-args", "-vvv extra verbose"]

'-f -m "Hello world" --extra-args "-vvv extra verbose"'.split
=> ["-f", "-m", "\"Hello", "world\"", "--extra-args", "\"-vvv", "extra", "verbose\""]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is [Shellwords](http://www.ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/Shellwords.html) if you're using 1.9. If you're not using 1.9 but do have Rails then you'll get [Shellwords](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Shellwords.html) from Rails. In either case, you can use `Shellwords.shellwords` to parse a string like a POSIX shell does:

```
>> Shellwords.shellwords("Where is 'pancakes house'?")
=> ["Where", "is", "pancakes house?"]
```

If you don't have Rails or 1.9 then you could probably just grab the `shellwords.rb` from Rails and use it.

**Update**: It looks like [Shellwords](http://www.ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.8/classes/Shellwords.html) is available in Ruby 1.8 (thank you Michael Khol). I was getting ambiguous results about which specific versions had it.

Comment: +1, but wanted to note that this also works in 1.8.7. (and even 1.8.6, I just tried). http://www.ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.8/classes/Shellwords.html

Comment: @Michael: Thanks, I was getting ambiguous information about which versions it was available in so I only included what I could verify.