# Parsing command line string in to argv format

Tags: c++, c, linux, exec

I need to parse a command line string in to the argv format so I can pass it in to execvpe. Basically a linux equivilant to CommandLineToArgvW() from Windows. Is there any function or library I could call to do this? Or do I have to write my own parser? (I was hoping I could steal from BASH if I needed to do this since my program is GPL...)

Example:
I have three variables:

```
const char* file = "someapplication";
const char* parameters = "param1 -option1 param2";
const char* environment[] = { "Something=something", NULL };
```

and I want to pass it to execvpe:

```
execvpe(file, /* parsed parameters */, environment);
```

PS: I do not want filename expansion but I want quoting and escaping

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3848603/12711

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse string into argv/argc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706551/parse-string-into-argv-argc)

Comment: Could you explain `wordexp()`? I don't understand it's manpage :/

Comment: If you don't want filename expansion, then I don't think `wordexp()` will do.

Comment: http://bbgen.net/blog/2011/06/string-to-argc-argv/

Comment: Seems reasonable. I'll try it. You should have posted it as a answer :o

Comment: A solution that supports bash-style escaping and weak/strong quoting: https://github.com/pasztorpisti/cmd2argv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the link given by rve in the comments (http://bbgen.net/blog/2011/06/string-to-argc-argv) and that solved my problem. Upvote his comment, not my answer!

Comment: The link given is broken

Comment: The web archive's got it though: http://web.archive.org/web/20121030075237/http://bbgen.net/blog/2011/06/string-to-argc-argv

Answer (score 1):

Use my `nargv` procedure. I've literally beaten this question to death with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10071763/735796 `nargv` means New Argument Vectors. It supports everything a shell would in regaurd to parsing a string into seperate elements. It supports double quotes, single quotes and string concatenation for example.

Comment: But still you don't link to the actual project. The question you mention above doesn't mention where to find it either... Here it is: https://github.com/hypersoft/nargv

Answer (score 0):

`char *strtok(char *s, const char *delim)` is what you are looking for

`char *s` will be standard input and `char *delim` will be `' '`

Comment: But would what happen if `s` had a `\ ` (Backslash space) somewhere in it?

Comment: This won't handle quoting (or globbing or any other shell-like behavior beyond splitting on spaces). It's not clear that OP needs that (even though bash is mentioned), but I think that at least quoting is likely important.

Comment: Oh ok I did not understand that.
Yeah it won't handle special characters, quoting etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but why don't you just pass the `&argv[1]` as parameters and the environment obtained using `getenv()` as environment?

**EDIT:**
If you want a different separator, you can use the environment variable IFS (internal field separator) to achieve this.

Comment: I'd assume he's interested in passing some other set of parameters that comes in the form of a string (maybe from a file or from interactive input).

Comment: Sounds reasonable, I've added a note about IFS, which may help too.

Answer (score 0):

The following is my first attempt at duplicating what the `CommandLineToArgvW()` function in the Windows shell library does.  It uses only standard functions and types, and does not use Boost.  Except for one call to `strdup()`, it is platform independent and works in both Windows and Linux environments.  It handles arguments that are single quoted or double quoted.

```cpp
// Snippet copied from a larger file.  I hope I added all the necessary includes.
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

char ** CommandLineToArgv( string const & line, int & argc )
{
    typedef vector<char *> CharPtrVector;
    char const * WHITESPACE_STR = " \n\r\t";
    char const SPACE = ' ';
    char const TAB = '\t';
    char const DQUOTE = '\"';
    char const SQUOTE = '\'';
    char const TERM = '\0';


    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Copy the command line string to a character array.
    // strdup() uses malloc() to get memory for the new string.
#if defined( WIN32 )
    char * pLine = _strdup( line.c_str() );
#else
    char * pLine = strdup( line.c_str() );
#endif


    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Crawl the character array and tokenize in place.
    CharPtrVector tokens;
    char * pCursor = pLine;
    while ( *pCursor )
    {
        // Whitespace.
        if ( *pCursor == SPACE || *pCursor == TAB )
        {
            ++pCursor;
        }

        // Double quoted token.
        else if ( *pCursor == DQUOTE )
        {
            // Begin of token is one char past the begin quote.
            // Replace the quote with whitespace.
            tokens.push_back( pCursor + 1 );
            *pCursor = SPACE;

            char * pEnd = strchr( pCursor + 1, DQUOTE );
            if ( pEnd )
            {
                // End of token is one char before the end quote.
                // Replace the quote with terminator, and advance cursor.
                *pEnd = TERM;
                pCursor = pEnd + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                // End of token is end of line.
                break;
            }
        }

        // Single quoted token.
        else if ( *pCursor == SQUOTE )
        {
            // Begin of token is one char past the begin quote.
            // Replace the quote with whitespace.
            tokens.push_back( pCursor + 1 );
            *pCursor = SPACE;

            char * pEnd = strchr( pCursor + 1, SQUOTE );
            if ( pEnd )
            {
                // End of token is one char before the end quote.
                // Replace the quote with terminator, and advance cursor.
                *pEnd = TERM;
                pCursor = pEnd + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                // End of token is end of line.
                break;
            }   
        }

        // Unquoted token.
        else
        {
            // Begin of token is at cursor.
            tokens.push_back( pCursor );

            char * pEnd = strpbrk( pCursor + 1, WHITESPACE_STR );
            if ( pEnd )
            {
                // End of token is one char before the next whitespace.
                // Replace whitespace with terminator, and advance cursor.
                *pEnd = TERM;
                pCursor = pEnd + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                // End of token is end of line.
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Fill the argv array.
    argc = tokens.size();
    char ** argv = static_cast<char **>( malloc( argc * sizeof( char * ) ) );
    int a = 0;
    for ( CharPtrVector::const_iterator it = tokens.begin(); it != tokens.end(); ++it )
    {
        argv[ a++ ] = (*it);
    }


    return argv;
}
```