# strstr for OR searching?

Tags: c

It may be a basic stuff, but i could not find a compact solution.
I am searching a string inside a larger string .
Since its hardware sometimes i am loosing input data, and so i would like to check if one of a few words are exist in a larger text , so :

```
strstr(wifiContent,"SEND OK  HTTP:  Connection:)
```

will search inside  `wifiContent` if these words appears in **this** combination , but i would like him to return >0 even if only **one** of them is appear in the string,

So for this input :

```
SEND OK BLA BLA BLA.. BLA BLA BLA.. HTTP: ...BLA BLA BLA... Connection...bla
```

I would like to get true(or index >0 ) for the search results.

How can i achieve this with `strstr` ?

EDIT:

I have tried without success this one :

```
 char * pch;
           char *scopy;
           strcpy(scopy,wifiContent);
            pch = strtok (scopy," ,.-");
            while (pch != NULL)
            {
             if( strstr(wifiContent,pch) )
              return 1;

              pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
            }

            if( strstr(wifiContent,target) )
               return 1;
```

Comment: Yes , in multiple calls to `strstr` you can get it done because strings are at different position in original string .

Comment: you can also use `fnmatch` and create a pattern as you wish. for example `"SEND OK * HTTP: * CONNECTION: *"

Comment: i dont understand.. i dont have multiple calls, i get some text string to search for, and this text is constructed from few words as i show - "SEND OK..." . so i have to  take this search string as it is, and check if one of its words appears in the larger text..

Comment: Just break it up into individual words. Or are you saying that's not possible for some reason?

Comment: how would i do that ? (sorry i am not a C programmer )

Comment: But a single `strstr` does not provide that functionality! So you have to write a function that breaks up your input into separate words and uses `strstr` for each.

Comment: exactly, thanks, but how you break it into words and then search ? in a compact way..

Comment: Look at `strtok`. But be mindful that it modifies the original string. So `strdup` the original search string first if it is a constant or if you want to keep it intact.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9659697/2564301.

Comment: You just need 3 calls to `strstr`  and if found increment `index` .

Comment: @ameyCU thanks, can you post answer with your way ? (assuming i dont know how many calls i will need, so i have to break the string into substrings and count for each)

Comment: Please check my edit, i show what i have been already tried

Comment: @Curnelious Do you consider `SEND OK` as same sub-string ? Or they are different ?

Comment: didn't get your question.. i would like to check if ONE of these words (separated by space) appears in the larger texts..

Comment: 'sometimes i am loosing input data' on what appears to be HTTP/TCP.  What's the betting that this is an XY problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have manage to do this , with the help of the great people in the comments :

```
                    char * pch;
                    pch = strtok (target," ");
                    while (pch != NULL)
                    {
                     if( strstr(wifiContent,pch) )
                      return 1;

                      pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
                    }

                    if( strstr(wifiContent,target) )
                       return 1;
```

Comment: well this one is not always working so i will be happy to get some comments about its flows.

Comment: Looks okay to me. Add `return 0` to the end if this is a separate function. Can you tell on what input it does not work?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple program to demonstrate how to do that -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main (void)
{
   char a[]="SEND OK BLA BLA BLA.. BLA BLA BLA.. HTTP: ...BLA BLA BLA... Connection...bla";  
   char s[]="SEND OK HTTP:  Connection";    //string with words you want to check
   char *ret ,*token;
   int index=0;                          // declare index
   token=strtok(s," ");                  // tokenize s 
   while(token!=NULL){                   // check return of strtok
       ret=strstr(a,token);              // search words 
       if(ret!=NULL)                     // check return of strstr
           index++;                      // increment index
       token=strtok(NULL," ");              
   }
   printf("%d",index);                   // print index
   return 0;
}
```

This will basically search those four words in you original string and increment `index` if any of those found .In this way your original string remains unchanged.

[Output of above program](https://ideone.com/glI8zl)

Comment: @M.M You are right , I was in impression that it will be changed (thought it is passed to `strtok`- Foolish of me (I got confused with `s` and `a` )). It turns out no need of it . Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

You could write:

```
return strstr(wifiContent, "SEND")
  || strstr(wifiContent, "OK")
  || strstr(wifiContent, "HTTP:")
  || strstr(wifiContent, "Connection");
```