# Dynamically adding elements to array C

Tags: c, arrays, execv

I am trying to build a function that takes a string of chars and provides a list of those chars separated by a token.

This is what I have so far:

```c
char * decode_args(char arguments[]){
  char* token = strtok(arguments, "00");
  while (token != NULL){
    printf("%s\n", token);
    token = strtok(NULL, "00");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This function prints the desired values that I am looking for. For example:

```c
>decode_args("77900289008764")
779
289
8764
```

The next step is to build an array that can be used in the `execv` command. The arguments need to be an array. [An example here](https://www.usna.edu/Users/cs/aviv/classes/ic221/s16/lec/14/lec.html). I am a beginner so I don't even know if "array" is the right word. What data type should be built and how can I do that so I can call `execv` with the arguments that are currently being printed in a list?

Comment: The linked example contains the proper type for the arguments: `char * ls_args[]`, i.e. you need an array of pointers to `char`.  Main challenge in your case is to know the number of arguments before defining the array. Please be aware that `strtok` modifies the initial string. This might make it a bit tricky to determine the number of arguments first and copy them into that array later.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse string into argv/argc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706551/parse-string-into-argv-argc)

Comment: Hm, ok, it looks like your delimiter shall be `00`. Note, that this is not what `strtok(..., "00");` does; `strtok()` only supports single character delimiters (albeit multiple of these), so this is equivalent to `strtok(..., "0");`. You could use `strstr()` or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters let me explain some stuff about storage and strings.

There are 3 basic storage types. Automatic, dynamic, static. And static one usually split into two: read-only and read-write. Dynamic and static ones will be useful for you soon.

Automatic variables are function parameters and local variables. When you call a function they pushed into stack and when function returns they got unwind.

Dynamic one is the one you allocate in runtime with `malloc` family. This is how we create a dynamic array. And you need to return this source when you are done with `free`. If you don't, it is called memory leak and you can check for memory leaks with the tool `valgrind` beside other memory errors. It is quite useful for systems programming class.

And static ones are the ones stay there for lifetime of the program.
If you define a global variable or `static int i = 42` it will create static read-write variable so you can change it. Now here is the trick.

```
void foo() {
   char *string1 = "hello, world" //static read-only
   char string2[] = "hello, world" //automatic
}
```

So if you try to change `string1` you will get a segmentation fault but it is OK to change `string2`. I don't know why you don't get segmentation fault by doing `decode_args("77900289008764")` but I get on my machine. :D

Now C-strings. They are null terminated which means there is a `(char) 0` character end of each string that says it is end of the string. `strtok` basically replace the pattern with `NULL` character so you have multiple substrings instead of one. So from your example it converts `"77900289008764 NULL"` to `"779 NULL 289 NULL 8764 NULL"`

So if I were you I would count encounters of "00" in the string and allocate that much character pointer. Which is something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char ** decode_args(char *arguments, char *delim) {
    int num_substrings = 1; // Note that C don't initialize with 0 like java etc.
    int len_delim = strlen(delim);

    for (int i = 0;
            arguments[i] != '\0' && arguments[i + 1] != '\0'; // Any of last 2 chars are terminator?
            ++i)
        if (strncmp(arguments + i /* same as &arguments[i] */, delim, len_delim) == 0)
            ++num_substrings;

    char **result = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * (num_substrings + 1));
    int i = 0;
    char* token = strtok(arguments, delim);

    while (token != NULL){
        result[i] = token;
        ++i;
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }

    result[i] = NULL; //End of results. execv wants this as I remember

    return result;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char str[] = "foo00bar00baz";
    char **results = decode_args(str, "00");

    for (int i = 0; results[i] != NULL; ++i) {
        char *result = results[i];
        puts(result);
    }

    free(results);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
#define MAX_ARGUMENTS 10

int decode_args(char arguments[], char ** pcListeArgs)
{
    int iNumElet = 0;
    char* token = strtok(arguments, "00");

    while ((token != NULL) && (iNumElet < MAX_ARGUMENTS -1)) 
    {
        size_t len = strlen(token);

        pcListeArgs [iNumElet] = (char*) calloc (len+1, sizeof (char));
        memset(pcListeArgs [iNumElet], 0, len+1); // reset content
        memcpy(pcListeArgs [iNumElet], token, len); // copy data

        token = strtok(NULL, "00");
        iNumElet++;
    }

    if ( iNumElet >= MAX_ARGUMENTS)
        return -1;

    return iNumElet;
}
```

And int the main :

```
int main() {

    char *pListArgs[MAX_ARGUMENTS];

    char args[] = "77900289008764";

    int iNbArgs = decode_args (args, pListArgs);

    if ( iNbArgs > 0)
    {
        for ( int i=0; i<iNbArgs; i++)
            printf ("Argument number %d = %s\n", i, pListArgs[i]);

        for ( int i=0; i<iNbArgs; i++)
            free (pListArgs[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

[image]